# Can cloud seeding make a much hotter summer, at a middle latitude, at the area that receives less water than expected?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, climate

My country, Spain (40ºN), receives clouds from the Atlantic Ocean during the summer. Our most visited beaches are on the Eastern coast, which sits on the Mediterranean Sea, there is typically more dry weather. The economy there depends on tourists, so imagine my government decides to do [**cloud seeding**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_seeding) the three or four times a low pressure area coming from the Atlantic can develop storms that reach the Mediterranean coast each summer.

Would we expect a much hotter summer at the Mediterranean because the low pressure area lose water?

Comment: Seems like cloud seeding isn't necessary for the purpose of this question.  You can analyze change in surface temperature due to storms regardless if cloud seeding is a factor.  Also, meteorology is highly dependent on regional factors... so it would be useful to put this question in terms of an actual location rather than a hypothetical location.

Comment: I edited the question @farrenthorpe i hoppe if someone of my gouvernement read it he do not start an investigation or take it like a public service if so :P It can be answered in therms of heat of a single storm, totaly correct.

Comment: I changed a bit the question sorry. I should use depression as term I think but it is anyhow related with the cooling effect of the storms received eg at mdt spain

Comment: I think you were better with storm.  We really only use depression for a specific designation in tropical development, but don't use it as it relates to everyday weather.  If you mean a larger low pressure with storms... I'd call them low pressure system (storms works too, but can be ambiguous)

Comment: I tried to rework some of the wording and typos to make it make question more clear.  I figure you should replace depression with "storm system" or "low pressure area" to make sense, but will wait for you to make that choice.

Comment: As to answer: a) I don't believe cloud seeding has shown large impacts... I think it's still hotly debated by some whether it even works at all. And b) if it does cause rain to fall out, it's actually adding more moisture to the area longterm, which in the air I suspect would just be blown away as the storm system departs. That extra water could evaporate later, so theoretically I'd expect cloud seeding that create extra rainfall to have a small cooling impact in areas where it is occurs (and not a huge different there, or in downwind spots that might theoretically lose the moisture removed)

Comment: Thank you again @JeopardyTempest . Yes I wanted to mean at summer we have our usuals anticyclons https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqkdP.png and from time to time low presure systems that use to develop in storms and electrical rays at the Peninsula. I realized the problem is more complicated than calculating the individual heat of a storm. Is that the low presure system would reach east coast more dry if we try to 'give tourists an umbrella'. I wondered if this could have influcence specialy at sea temperature.

Comment: It is important as a particularity at Spain the orientation of [Ebro Valley][1] Also at the north coast some valleys have NW-SE orientation. [1]: https://google.es/maps/@41.5324428,-1.6251139,434064m/data=!3m1!1e3